# Why does Sanderson talks to Paul as if they've met before?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-rum-diary

In *The Rum Diary (2011)*, Paul has to take an interview from the Mayor who will arrive at the Airport, But the Mayor's plane got cancelled. So Paul met Sanderson who invites him to his home.

Paul had never met Sanderson before in the movie, so why then does Sanderson talk to Paul as if they've met before?